# When I debug deadlock situation disappers... So how the heck I find the error?

Tags: c, multithreading, debugging, deadlock

Sorry, I'm about to go crazy! When I print messages in my C code, deadlock does not occur. But when i don't print them, i sometimes see a deadlock. Program doesn't work properly and waits forever.

How am I supposed to find out the problematic situation?

Any other methods which learning curve is small?

If you wanna see the code, let me know. Since its pretty complex, i didn't put it here.

Comment: That's not uncommon - the prints are synchronized (at some level), and introduce ordering into your code. This can be enough to hide the data race which causes the deadlock. Can't you debug the code once deadlocked, see who's locked, and work your way backwards?

Comment: "Can't you debug the code once deadlocked" How can I do that?

Comment: If you're not running it using a debugger, attach one to the code once it hangs, and examine the stacks of the hanged threads. Can't say more because I have no idea what's your development environment.

Comment: "attach one to the code once it hangs" sorry. what is "one"?

Comment: A debugger. What's your development environment? VC, GCC etc.

Comment: i'm using gcc. i tried using gdb  but  `gdb ./wcountb 3 5 file1 file2 file3 o 100` gives me error.

Comment: `Attaching to program: /home/a/os/p3/wcountb, process 3
Could not attach to process.  If your uid matches the uid of the target
process, check the setting of /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope, or try
again as the root user.  For more details, see /etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf
ptrace: Operation not permitted.
/home/a/os/p3/3: No such file or directory.`

Comment: I'm not familiar with those errors. Try solving them first (ask a separate question if you can't find the answer). Once you have a usable gdb, the rest will be easier.

Answer (score 0):

eran's comments contain some good ideas.  Another approach you can use that might be complementary is to do your debug output to separate files per-process or per-thread so that your prints don't impose any ordering.  There's still a possibility that the time spent writing will throw off the timing enough to prevent the deadlock, but it's not a given.  Sometimes separate logs per process are easier to read than interleaved ones anyways.